# how to make opengl animation with transparent background?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

This is my code, but I cannot make it move.

I had add some code int `rendSC()` when every times execute at this function, I add 1 pix at y axis.

but it not moving. only show the first time it draw.

this is some way that I'd tried:

1. force call `rendsc()` in loop. failure
2. can `UpdateWindow()` `InvalidWindow()` etc.. to refresh window, it call the `rendSC()` in event now. also failure
3. use time to call `rendSC()`. failure.

   ```
   #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

   #include <windows.h>
   #include <windowsx.h>
   #include <GL/gl.h>
   #include <GL/glu.h>

   #pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
   #pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")

   #include <assert.h>
   #include <tchar.h>

   #ifdef  assert
   #define verify(expr) if(!expr) assert(0)
   #else verify(expr) expr
   #endif

   const TCHAR szAppName[]=_T("TransparentGL");
   const TCHAR wcWndName[]=_T("WS_EX_LAYERED OpenGL");

   HDC hDC;            
   HGLRC m_hrc;        
   int w(240);
   int h(240); 

   HDC pdcDIB;                 
   HBITMAP hbmpDIB;            
   void *bmp_cnt(NULL);        
   int cxDIB(0); 
   int cyDIB(0);   
   BITMAPINFOHEADER BIH;       


   BOOL initSC()
   {
       glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);        
       glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);        
       glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

       glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);          
       glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);            

       glEnable(GL_BLEND);             
       glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
       glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

       return 0;
   }

   void resizeSC(int width,int height)
   {
       glViewport(0,0,width,height);
       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
       glLoadIdentity();

       glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW );
       glLoadIdentity();
   }

   BOOL renderSC()
   {   
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

       glPushMatrix();

       glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
       glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
           glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Red
           glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
           glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Green
           glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
           glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);                      // Set The Color To Blue
           glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
       glEnd();

       glPopMatrix();
       glFlush();

       return 0;
   }

   // DIB -> hDC
   void draw(HDC pdcDest)
   {
       assert(pdcDIB);

       verify(BitBlt(pdcDest, 0, 0, w, h, pdcDIB, 0, 0, SRCCOPY));
   }

   void CreateDIB(int cx, int cy)
   {
       assert(cx > 0); 
       assert(cy > 0);

       cxDIB = cx ;
       cyDIB = cy ;

       int iSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);   
       memset(&BIH, 0, iSize);

       BIH.biSize = iSize;
       BIH.biWidth = cx;   
       BIH.biHeight = cy;  
       BIH.biPlanes = 1;   
       BIH.biBitCount = 24;    
       BIH.biCompression = BI_RGB;

       if(pdcDIB) 
           verify(DeleteDC(pdcDIB));

       pdcDIB = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
       assert(pdcDIB);

       if(hbmpDIB) 
           verify(DeleteObject(hbmpDIB));

       hbmpDIB = CreateDIBSection(
           pdcDIB,         
           (BITMAPINFO*)&BIH,  
           DIB_RGB_COLORS,     
           &bmp_cnt,       
           NULL,
           0);

       assert(hbmpDIB);
       assert(bmp_cnt);

       if(hbmpDIB)
           SelectObject(pdcDIB, hbmpDIB);
   }

   BOOL CreateHGLRC()
   {
       DWORD dwFlags = PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP;

       PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd ;
       memset(&pfd,0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR)) ;
       pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR); 
       pfd.nVersion = 1;                       
       pfd.dwFlags =  dwFlags ;                
       pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA ;        
       pfd.cColorBits = 24 ;                   
       pfd.cDepthBits = 32 ;                   
       pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE ;       

      int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(pdcDIB, &pfd);
      if (PixelFormat == 0){
         assert(0);
         return FALSE ;
      }

      BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(pdcDIB, PixelFormat, &pfd);
      if (bResult==FALSE){
         assert(0);
         return FALSE ;
      }

      m_hrc = wglCreateContext(pdcDIB);
      if (!m_hrc){
         assert(0);
         return FALSE;
      }

      return TRUE;
   }

   LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
       PAINTSTRUCT ps;

       switch(msg) 
       {
           case WM_ERASEBKGND:
               return 0;
           break;

           case WM_CREATE:
           break;

           case WM_DESTROY:
               if(m_hrc)
               {
                   wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
                   wglDeleteContext(m_hrc) ;
               }
               PostQuitMessage(0) ;
           break;

           case WM_PAINT:
               hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
               renderSC(); // OpenGL -> DIB
               draw(hDC);  // DIB -> hDC
               EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
           break;

           case WM_SIZE:
               w = LOWORD(lParam); h = HIWORD(lParam);         
               wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
               wglDeleteContext(m_hrc);

               CreateDIB(w, h);
               CreateHGLRC();
               verify(wglMakeCurrent(pdcDIB, m_hrc));

               initSC();
               resizeSC(w, h);
               renderSC();
           break;

           default: 
               return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
       }

       return 0;
   }

   int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str,int nWinMode)
   {   
       WNDCLASSEX wc;
       memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
       wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
       wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
       wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
       wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowFunc;
       wc.cbClsExtra  = 0;
       wc.cbWndExtra  = 0;
       wc.hInstance = hThisInst;
       wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
       wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
       wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW);
       wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

       if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
       {
           MessageBox(NULL, _T("RegisterClassEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
           return FALSE;
       }

       HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, szAppName, wcWndName,
                       WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 200, 150, w, h,
                       NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);
       if(!hWnd){
           MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
           return FALSE;
       }

       verify(SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0x0, 0, LWA_COLORKEY));

       MSG msg;
       while(1) 
       {
           while (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_NOREMOVE)){
               if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
               {
                   TranslateMessage(&msg);
                   DispatchMessage(&msg);
               }
               else return 0;
           }
       } 

       return (FALSE); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Drawing into bitmap context is a bad idea. You'll get only software context in that case (that also means you'll get version 1.1 context without any useful extensions).

However, if that suits your needs, you are creating non double buffered context, in that case you should call `glFinish` (not Flush) before you can copy bits from DIB to window.

Prefer using double buffered window context, with `PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW` and avoid draw to bitmap context.

If you still want to get rendering result into DIB, you should learn about rendering to texture techniques like FBO (to render scene into texture) and grabbing data back by reading pixels from texture (there are also couple of ways you can do that).

Comment: can u give me a demo code? because i'm so poor in opengl.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Moving quad on the screen?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials online, why don't you pick one?

Comment: because i cannot find it. I'd ever try sfml freeglut glut and so on, but cannot find a tutorials that can do what i want. Maybe the reason is my poor english, or i'm not a win32 developer in these times. if u know the keywords in google can search it, please tell me, thank u very much!

Comment: Well, tutorials are to explain general concepts, so you can do what you want yourself. You probably won't find tutorial which will do exactly what you want. Here's a good site for modern  OpenGL: https://learnopengl.com Hello OpenGL is not usual hello world program with one print statement, it definitely requires more knowledge. Invest some time in learning and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

now, this can make such a window

but if i click the window, it will be freeze

```
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#endif

GLFWwindow* f_window = NULL;
float ratio = 0;
int width, height;

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

static void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int a, int b, int c)
{
    int xxx = 0;
}

#ifdef _WIN32

void Render();
void renderFunc();
void timerGlFunc();



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static bool toDebug = false;

    if (toDebug)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " "; printf("%02x", msg); std::cout << " ";
        toDebug = false;
    }
    //std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " " << msg;

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        int xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " "; printf("%02x", msg); std::cout << " ";
        toDebug = true;
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM(xPos, yPos));
    }
        break;
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " "; printf("%02x", msg); std::cout << " ";
        toDebug = true;
        break;
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " "; printf("%02x", msg); std::cout << " ";
        toDebug = true;
        break;
    case WM_CAPTURECHANGED:
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " "; printf("%02x", msg); std::cout << " ";
        toDebug = true;
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if (wParam == 1)
        {
            timerGlFunc();
        }

        //DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

        break;
    default:
        //Render();
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

}

#endif

void mainDraw();


int main(void)
{
    bool first = true;
    std::thread t(mainDraw);
    while (true)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            t.detach();
            first = false;
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


    return 0;
}

void mainDraw()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_MASK, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    char* title = "Transparent window example";
    window = glfwCreateWindow(256, 256, title, NULL, NULL);

#ifdef _WIN32
    HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, title);
    if (windowHandle == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL HWND");
    }
    SetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)WndProc);

    SetTimer(windowHandle, 1, 20, NULL);
#endif

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    f_window = window;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glfwSetWindowPos(window, 300, 300);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_callback);

    renderFunc();
    //Sleep(10);


    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
}

void renderFunc()
{
    BOOL ret;
    MSG msg;
    /*
    while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (ret != -1)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    */

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(f_window))
    {
        if ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) != 0)
        {
            if (ret != -1)
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(f_window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float)glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

        //Render();

        Sleep(10);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void timerGlFunc()
{
    if (!glfwWindowShouldClose(f_window))
    {
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(f_window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float)glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

        Render();

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void Render()
{


    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
    glColor4f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
    glEnd();

    glfwSwapBuffers(f_window);
}
```